# Adjust bootstrap menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing this bootstrap menu [Bootstrap Menu](http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz)
and it works, the problem is open the sub menus, if I have many options it always open to the right and some options get out of the screen or are incomplete.[Like this](http://screencast.com/t/UTa9J58x1U)

This is the CSS and JQuery

```js
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); 
   event.stopPropagation(); 
   $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.marginBottom-0 {margin-bottom:0;}

.dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;

}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{
    display:block;
    content:" ";
    float:right;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color:#cccccc;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:-10px;

}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{
    border-left-color:#555;

}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left{
    float:none;

}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{
    left:-100%;
    margin-left:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;

}
```

The correct is open to the left if there is no space but i dont have idea how make the change.

Hope someone can help me or show me an example.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, please share the code that you written so that I could get a better sense of your issue. Since I don't have a full picture, I will list some potential solutions:

1. CSS classes

   - `dropdown-submenu pull-left` or `dropdown-submenu pull-right`
2. Media queries

   - Media queries allow you to implement a certain UI/UX/Interface during events where the viewport matches a certain rule
3. Mix of both

   - It seems like the issue you're running into is that the UI doesn't look right at certain viewports. So I would run build a media query that will change the CSS class of a given element so that the submenu will show up on the left vs right.

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide actual code instead of links to your question to get help easier and people can actually understand your problem and avoid guess-work.

Apart from that, try to add `.dropdown-pull-right` class at your `ul.dropdown-menu`. This might fix it.